# React Render HTML to Infowindow using @React-Google-Maps/api

Tags: html, reactjs, google-maps, infowindow

How do I to render html in google maps Infowindow?

I have tried several different ways to do it, but none of them seems to work.

My code :

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import { GoogleMap, LoadScript, useLoadScript, InfoWindow, Marker, } from '@react-google-maps/api'

export class MarkerWithInfoWindow extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            isOpen: false
        }
        this.onToggleOpen = this.onToggleOpen.bind(this);
        this.onEventWindowClick = this.onEventWindowClick.bind(this)
    }

    onToggleOpen() {
        this.setState({
            isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
        });
    }



    render() {

        const imgUrl = this.props.icon;
        return (<Marker
            title={this.props.title}
            position={this.props.position}

            icon={{
                url: imgUrl,
            }}
        >
            {this.state.isOpen && <InfoWindow
                onCloseClick={this.onToggleOpen}
                position={this.props.position}
                onMouseOut={this.onToggleOpen}
                pixelOffset={{ width: 25, height: 25 }}
                zIndex={-1}
                onClick={this.onEventWindowClick(this)} 
            >
                <> {ReactDOMServer.renderToString(this.props.content)}</>
            </InfoWindow>}
        </Marker>)
    }
}
```

my result looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess `content` prop is passed as HTML string, then [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) needs to be set to render it as html instead of returning it as a plain string, for instance:

```
const InfoWindowContent = () => <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.content }}></div>;
```

Usage

```
<InfoWindow
     onCloseClick={this.onToggleOpen}
     position={this.props.position}>
      <InfoWindowContent/>
</InfoWindow>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jl7wg8)

Answer (score 0):

I've done this only as a functional component. According to the Google Map API docs, the desired HTML content can be passed as the value of the `content` property of the InfoWindow instance at its instantiation. According to the documentation of the `react-google-maps/api`, the (initial) options can be passed as a prop in the `InfoWindow` JSX.

In my case, I recompute the InfoWindow content on the fly, so I keep that string as a piece of state (`dataWindowContent` in my case). React guarantees that the InfoWindow component will be rerendered each time the state changes, so that's how I keep mine current.

Finally, the InfoWindow component is created with the InfoWindow component open by default. I keep mine closed until it has something to show, so I put that behavior in the onInfoWindowLoad handler.

You'll need a ref to the underlying Google Maps API instance -- the InfoWindow component conveniently passes that object as an argument when it invokes the onLoad handler. So here's a sketch of how you might do what you're attempting (note that I haven't exercised this, I'm just trying to say what you might try):

```
const MarkerWithInfoWindow = ( {content, title, position, icon, ...props} ) => {
  const [infoWindowContent, setInfoWindowContent] = useState(content);
  const [localPosition, setLocalPosition] = useState(position);
  const rawInfoWindowRef = useRef(null);

  const onInfoWindowLoad = (aRawInfoWindow) => {
    rawInfoWindowRef.current = aRawInfoWindow;
    if (''===infoWindowContent) {
      aRawInfoWindow.close();
    }
  };
  return (
    <GoogleMap>
      <Marker
        title={title}
        position={localPosition}
        icon={{url: icon}}
      >
      <InfoWindow
        onLoad={onInfoWindowLoad}
        onCloseClick={onInfoWindowClick}
        options={{content: infoWindowContent}}
        position={localPosition}         
      />
      </Marker>
    <GoogleMap>
  );
};
```

Note that I've passed your desired HTML into the InfoWindow instance as the value of its `content` parameter inside its `option` prop.

Note also that `position` and `content` props are used to initialize the corresponding local state. Use their setters to move the marker/infoWindow or move the map. Also note I've surrounded your Marker and InfoWindow with a containing GoogleMap. I'm pretty sure the components require this container. You might need set the `center` property of the containing map as another piece of state so that it changes if the position changes.

This approach lets you avoid the use of `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. The only way to change infoWindowContent is to use its setter (`setInfoWindowContent`) and this will force a rerender of the component tree. In that re-render, the low-level InfoWindow instance will be updated with its new content automatically, and it will render the HTML.